# Integrate url parameters

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there a way to construct a local link with parameters that will work in both test and prod? I was planning to hard code it but realized the first part of the link being different would cause problems. (yes, I can create a script variable but that isn't ideal).

By this I mean links that end with `#Files?id=100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is! You need to use this on the server script:

```
var appUrl = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
appUrl += "#Files?id=100;
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#getUrl()